# drive -> hard-drive tag synonym suggestion

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-request

Currently there are 110 questions tagged with [drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/drive). I suggested making [drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/drive) a [synonym](https://superuser.com/tags/hard-drive/synonyms) for [hard-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hard-drive). I realize that *drive* and *hard-drive* it is not exactly the same (some drives are not hard-drives), but browsing the current [drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/drive) questions, I see that most of them could be safely retagged as hard-drive. So, such synonym is probably safe.

The problem that I see with this [drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/drive) tag is this:

While most of questions are about hard drives, a few are about completely unrelated things:

- CD/DVD drives
- USB flash media
- Network drives
- Floppy drives

All these things have their respective tags of course. So in my opinion, generic "drive" tag as it stands now is too broad to be of any use.

Comment: What about USB drives? Disc drives? I just saw a couple of questions related to those. Examples: [Have optical drive connectors changed in the last year?](http://superuser.com/questions/367822/have-optical-drive-connectors-changed-in-the-last-year), [DVD drive not detected in BIOS / Windows XP](http://superuser.com/questions/403689/dvd-drive-not-detected-in-bios-windowsxp), [how format a usb drive in the right way? (FAT 32 to NTFS)](http://superuser.com/questions/391049/how-format-a-usb-drive-in-the-right-way-fat-32-to-ntfs)

Comment: Most questions about "USB drives" tagged with "drive" talk about external hard drives... There are a couple of questions about USB sticks and CD/DVD drives, true... Maybe the correct answer should be not to create a synonym, but retag somehow? I'll amend my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the comments, I would agree on that:

- Go through [drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/drive) and retag all those that are *not* about [hard-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hard-drive) accordingly.
- After that, create the synonym [drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/drive) ← [hard-drive](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hard-drive) as suggested.

Comment: I'll do it over a couple of days to prevent flooding the home page...

Comment: This would additionally remove ambiguity, which would be a good thing.  When mentioning a drive by way of tag, it would be beneficial to know which kind of drive.  Granted the sub-group the drive is a member of may be mentioned in the question, but if the question is (at least partially) centered around a drive, having clarity as to which kind of drive would be important.